# SQL to count() specific records in in a different *AND* same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is similar to another question I asked recently, but goes a little further.

My previous question asked how I could construct a view with `tblCurrent` whilst retrieving a count of specific, related records from `tblHistorical`.

I *now* want to know how to do the same, but to add two additional columns that count records based on specific criteria from the same `tblCurrent` table.

I have two tables:

```
tblCurrent 
 Ref  | CustomerID | Category | Subcategory | Resolved | ... .. .. .  . |
X001  | 001        | Sales  |  Major      |  TRUE  
X002  | 002        | Sales  | Minor      |  FALSE
X003  | 001        | Marketing | Corp      |  TRUE  


tblHistorical 
 Ref   | ... .. .. .  . |  Missing | Matched
X001   | ... .. .. .  . |  TRUE    | FALSE
X001   | ... .. .. .  . |  FALSE   | FALSE
X002   | ... .. .. .  . |  TRUE    | TRUE
X002   | ... .. .. .  . |  TRUE    | FALSE
X003   | ... .. .. .  . |  FALSE   | FALSE
X003   | ... .. .. .  . |  TRUE    | TRUE
```

Ref is unique in tblCurrent, but not in Historical.

I was advised and successfully got to work the following for the previous question:

```
SELECT  a.ref,
    SUM(CASE WHEN b.Missing = 'True' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) missingTrue,
    SUM(CASE WHEN b.Missing = 'False' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) missingFalse,
    SUM(CASE WHEN b.Matched = 'True' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) matchTrue
FROM    tblCurrent a
    LEFT JOIN tblHistorical b
        on a.ref = b.ref
GROUP BY a.ref
```

Q: How do I add two additional columns (to the above solution) that count:

- Number of records in `tblCurrent` that match the same `CustomerID` + `Category` (but not current record) AND Resolved=False.
- Number of records in `tblCurrent` that match the same `CustomerID` + `Category` + `SubCategory` (but not current record) AND Resolved=False.

Comment: It would be better if you could give an example output based on your current question's data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

SELECT  a.ref, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN b.Missing = 'True' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) missingTrue, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN b.Missing = 'False' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) missingFalse, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN b.Matched = 'True' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) matchTrue ,
    COUNT(DISTINCT a.CustomerID) as CustomerID_count --< add this line
FROM    tblCurrent a 
    LEFT JOIN tblHistorical b 
        on a.ref = b.ref 
GROUP BY a.ref

**EDIT:**

As per your  updated question, If I understand your question correctly,

```
;WITH 
CATEGORY   AS 
        (SELECT CustomerID ,Category,COUNT(*) AS CNT
        FROM tblCurrent
        GROUP BY CustomerID ,Category),

SUBCATEGORY AS 
        (SELECT CustomerID ,Category,SubCategory,COUNT(*) AS CNT
        FROM tblCurrent
        GROUP BY CustomerID ,Category,SubCategory),

MAIN        AS (
SELECT  a.ref,
        SUM(CASE WHEN b.Missing = 'True' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) missingTrue,
        SUM(CASE WHEN b.Missing = 'False' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) missingFalse,
        SUM(CASE WHEN b.Matched = 'True' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) matchTrue
        FROM    tblCurrent a
        LEFT JOIN tblHistorical b
            on a.ref = b.ref
        GROUP BY a.ref
)
SELECT M.* ,C.CNT AS CATEGORY_COUNT,
       S.CNT AS SUBCATEGORY_COUNT
FROM    MAIN M
JOIN    tblCurrent T
ON      M.ref=T.ref
JOIN    CATEGORY C
ON      C.CustomerID=T.CustomerID
AND     C.Category=T.Category
JOIN    SUBCATEGORY S
ON      S.CustomerID=T.CustomerID
AND     C.Category=T.Category
AND     S.SubCategory=T.SubCategory
```

Comment: Joe, not quite there, I need to be able to count the number of records in the same table, based on at least two fields, CustomerID and Category. A second column would do the same, but one additional criteria field.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this with CTE:

```
WITH tmp AS (
   SELECT CustomerId, COUNT(*) AS cnt
   FROM tblCurrent)
SELECT a.ref, tmp.cnt, ...
FROM tblCurrent a
LEFT JOIN tblHistorical b
   ON a.ref = b.ref
LEFT JOIN tmp
   ON tmp.CustomerId = a.CustomerId
...
```

Comment: Brenda, not quite there, I need to be able to count the number of records in the same table, based on at least two fields, CustomerID and Category. A second column would do the same, but one additional criteria field. Appreciate your input.

Comment: After looking at this all weekend and discussing it with a colleage when I came in, you may actually be on the right route, I just need to add additional fields / criteria to the tmp table, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `COUNT(DISTINCT )` to a tblCurrent's unique ID - ie:

```
SELECT  a.ref, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT tblCurrent.Ref),
    SUM(CASE WHEN b.Missing = 'True' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) missingTrue, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN b.Missing = 'False' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) missingFalse, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN b.Matched = 'True' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) matchTrue 
FROM    tblCurrent a 
    LEFT JOIN tblHistorical b 
        on a.ref = b.ref 
GROUP BY a.ref
```

Comment: I've updated my description with more detail. I need two count columns and they both need to be based on more than one criteria field. Check the main question for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use more than one condition in a CASE statement.  So you can do "CASE WHEN a=b AND c=d THEN 1 ELSE 0 END".  Does that help?

Comment: Jim, unfortunately no, my current issue is that the two additional columns are based on tblCurrent (the main table), so trying to work out how to add them.